# How to check that user input is not greater than a decimal?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Js game and when you have $11.54 in balance and try to bet $1054 it will run.

```
function roundBet(){
    if (balance == 0){
        alert("Sorry you have any money left.")
    }

    else{
        userBet = prompt("How much do you want to bet this round?\nYou have $" + balance)

        while(userBet <= 0 || isNaN(userBet) || userBet == ""){
            userBet = prompt("User Input: " + userBet + "\nSorry your input was invalid.\nHow much do you want to bet this round?\nYou have: $" + balance + " to play with")
        }

        while(userBet > balance){
            userBet = prompt("User Input: " + userBet + "\nSorry you don't have enough balance.\nYou have $" + balance + " to play with")
        }

        if(userBet <= balance){
            alert("You bet $" + userBet)
            moneyPlaced = Number(moneyPlaced) + Number(userBet)
            balance = balance - userBet
            update()
            //Resets user bet to 0
            userBet = 0;
        }

        else{
            roundBet()
        }
        moneyPlaced = Number(moneyPlaced) + Number(userBet)
        //highLow()
    }
}
```

I expected it to alert an error, as you are trying to bet $1054 when you only have $11.54

Comment: You need to convert `userBet` to number first

Comment: Are you using variables without declaring them?

Comment: Declare your variables on first use, so they aren't global. Instead of `while(contition){code}` use `do {code} while(condition}`. That way you can check all the conditions at one time. As it is now you first ask the user for a bet, and check for NaN, but in the second you don't.

Comment: Oh, the question was closed before I could show you a better way to do your while loop. Use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert to a number: `userBet = parseFloat(prompt("How much do you want to bet this round?\nYou have $" + balance));`

Comment: parseFloat will return NaN if the input is an empty string, so you no longer need to check for that.